# Error in Neukirch's "Algebraic Number Theory"?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I found what I believe is an error in Neukirch's book, in Chapter 1 Section 3 (Ideals).  Exercise 5 states

> The quotient ring $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{a}$ of a dedekind domain by an ideal $\mathfrak{a} \neq 0$ is a principal ideal domain.

I believe I can prove every ideal in the quotient $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{a}$ is principal, but this need not be a domain, correct? (i.e. $\mathbb{Z}/(4)$ )

This seems obvious, but I just need some validation otherwise I'll feel crazy.

Comment: If it weren't trivial, I would suggest that he'd forgotten to specify *prime* ideals.  Alas, those quotients just give fields, by definition of a Dedekind domain, so most likely he meant to write "principal ideal *ring*".

Comment: Translation error. In the original german version it says "Hauptidealring".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right. In this situation, the quotient ring is necessarily a principal Artinian ring, but not necessarily a domain. See Pete L. Clark's answer [here.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72229/quotients-of-number-rings/72265#72265)

Comment: Thanks! Glad to know I'm not going *completely* crazy